# jQuery problem with event firing

Tags: jquery

```
$('.sss').click(function() {
  $("#a"+id).html("<textarea id=\"txt\" rows=\"8\" cols=\"75\">fddscx</textarea> <br />"+
                  "<input type=\"button\" id=\"xxx\" value=\"Do smth button\" class=\"submit_button\" />");
});

$('#xxx').click(function() {
    alert("button happened");
});
```

I click something which has class `sss`. Then a button appears which has id `xxx`. Why doesn't it give me an alert when I click it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work because your button was dynamically added to the document and you added click event to an element that doesn't exist yet. It will exist after you click the `.sss` element.

You have two options to solve your problem:

### Workaround solution: use `live()`/`.delegate()` instead of `.click()`

Instead of using `.click()` you can use `.live()` which binds events to existing as well as future elements (but don't think of it as a silver bullet and start using it everywhere). This actually binds a click event to `document` and checks whether actual click event was fired on an element that matches selector. This means that `live()` (and `.delegate()` as well) functionality gets executed much more frequently doing all these checks. So use it wisely:

```
$('#xxx').live("click", function() {
    alert("button happened");
})
```

### Best solution: attach even after you've created your button

The best and correct way would of course be to bind your event after you've created your element. And that's in the click event of the `.sss` element:

```
$('.sss').click(function() {

    $("#a"+id).html("<textarea id=\"txt\" rows=\"8\" cols=\"75\">fddscx</textarea> <br />"+
                    "<input type=\"button\" id=\"xxx\" value=\"Do smth button\" class=\"submit_button\" />");
    $('#xxx').click(function() {
        alert("button happened");
    })
})
```

I suggest you use the second solution.

## Let's compare these solutions

### Event registration

`.click()` and `.live()` both have to execute jQuery selector first then bind the event (`.click()` directly to selected elements, `.live()` to `documement` and saves jQuery selector along with it no matter whether any elements with that selector existed or not).

`.delegate()` selects one elements to which it will bind the event. Similarly to `.live()` it also saved selector.

### Execution speed

`.click()` is the clear winner here, because it will execute directly on the element withou any overhead of selector matching.

`.delegate()` and `.live()` both have some overhead of selector matching. But the bigger problem is that imagine that user click all over the document (which is very common since user interacts regularly with clicks). Every single click is evaluated when `.live()` has been used. And depending on the container selection of `.delegate()` the same can be said. They both execute much much more events than they actually should be executed.

When a click happens, it gets bubbled up all the way to its container (be it `document` r some other container associated with `.delegate()`). Every click has to be evaluated whether target elements matches selector. If it does, jQuery also executes event handler provided along with `.live()` or `.delegate()` event binding.

### Verdict

Executing a jQuery selector once is still not that bad compared to evaluating selector eac time a user clicks something (whatever) in the document. Hence I find `.live()` and `.delegate()` event registration similar and should be avoided whenever possible.

Use direct event binding when possible. It is the fastest possible execution which usually happens much more often than event registration.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik - why live rather than delegate?

Comment: @dhinesh yeah, sure I know it works however there is more overhead with live and it is only in the api for legacy reasons.

Comment: @redsquare: Well because he didn't say that he'll always put that button in a particular container. And in case common ancestor is `BODY` it doesn't really matter whether you use `live` or `delegate`. They'll both bind to the same element making them equal. Actually when you use one over the other I suppose it doesn't matter that much any more. The main difference is that using `delegate` click evaluating may happen less often.

Comment: Further reading in this regard: [The Difference Between jQuery’s .bind(), .live(), and .delegate()](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/)

Comment: @redqueare: where did you read that `live()` is obsolete and part of lib for compatibility reasons and `delegate()` should be used instead? They both serve a very similar but still a different purpose. Hence both being valid solutions.

Comment: Another difference delegate does not need to query all .sss elements up front when setting up the handler.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik read any slide deck regarding jq & selector performance.

Comment: @redsquare: Best solution still being the one to attach `click` after element creation. Better than `live` or `delegate`. It's wise to avoid any of those `live`/`delegate` event delegation if at all possible. And `live` is still very viable solution if you know what you're doing. Performace loss is at the beginning when you select an element for `live` event binding. Afterwards they're pretty much the same when set...

Comment: @redsquare: That's true about getting `.sss` elements. But executing delegated event (100x) and evaluating selector match is still lot slower than direct event binding using my second approach.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik  - sorry I disagree - if he clicks 100 times on an .sss element you will add 100 separate handlers to the dom. How is that ever better than using delegation? Also if you use x live handlers they all get evaluated at the body. Delegating to a container that is not the body is far better.

Comment: @redsquare: Let's be practical here and not exaggerate things. Glancing his code he's giving his button an ID. That means that he obviously want to have just one element. Clicking on `.sss` multiple times doesn't seem real in this situation. And even if he did, he could save HTML into a variable and register event directly without using jQuery selector. HTML generation would happen always anyway. Direct `.click()` binding is still his best solution. Whether you agree or not.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik Again I disagree - he is using a class selector which assumes he has > 1 element to click on.

Comment: @redsquare: You disagree on what? that using `.delegate()` is wiser than using `.click()`. Fine. Use it that way. I won't.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik Calm down, why take it personally. We are just having a discussion so no need to get defensive. You stated "That means that he obviously want to have just one element." If that was the case why does your best solution not mention .one? Hard to tell because we cant see any clean up code he may invoke on the click of the new button etc etc. We are here to educate. I can imply from the question that he has multiple .sss elements therefore delegate is the way to go, regardless if the OP understands that a dom should only have one unique element id

Comment: I'm not taking it personally. I didn't want to continue fruitless argument over which event binding is best. And BTW: why would you want to assign the same HTML (not to mention generating it) multiple times and assigning it to `A`? I think he has only one `.sss` and it's supposed to be clicked **only once**. Over-engineering is an overkill.

Answer (score 3):

It does not work because you create the handler before the element is part of the dom.
You should use [.delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) on the container element. Delegate allows you to handle events for current and future elements.

An example in your case would be

```
function clickHandler(){

     alert("button happened");

}

$('#someContainer').delegate('.sss', 'click' , clickHandler);
```